# C++ member functions with same name and parameters, different return type

Tags: c++

is it valid if I define member functions with same name&parameters but different return types inside a class like this:

```
class Test {
public:
    int a;
    double b;
}

class Foo {    
private:
    Test t;
public:
    inline Test &getTest() {
        return t;
    }
    inline const Test &getTest() const {
        return t;
    }
}
```

Which member function gets called if we have following code?

```
Foo foo;  // suppose foo has been initialized
Test& t1 = foo.getTest();
const Test& t2 = foo.getTest();
```

Comment: your functions _do not have the same signature_...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

no, it is not valid, but in your example it is, because the last `const` is actually *part of the signature* (the hidden `Foo *this` first parameter is now `const Foo *this`).

It is used to access in read-only (get const reference, the method is constant), or write (get non-const reference, the method is not constant)

it's still a good design choice to return the reference of the same entity (constant or non-constant) in both methods of course!

Comment: In other words, the last `const` modifies the type of the implicit `this` parameter, so it can be thought to change the parameter types of the function.

Comment: Yes, and though it is not very popular among the average C++ coders. Too bad.

Answer (score 3):

No.

You cannot overload on return type.

Why? The standard says so.

And it actually makes sense - you can't determine what function to call in all situations.

Answer (score 3):

Const and non-const methods with the same formal parameter list can appear side-by-side because the this pointer is treated as a hidden argument and would have a different type.  This may be used to provide mutating and non-mutating accessors as in the code in your question.

If the signatures are exactly the same, then no.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon the previous answers and your given code with an example so you can actually tell what's being called when:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {
public:
    int a;
    double b;
};

class Foo {
private:
    Test t;
public:
    inline Test &getTest() {
        std::cout << "Non const-refrence " << std::endl;
        return t;
    }
    inline const Test &getTest() const {
        std::cout << "Const-refrence " << std::endl;
        return t;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    Test& t1 = foo.getTest();
    const Test& t2 = foo.getTest();

    const Foo bar;
    const Test& t3 = bar.getTest();

    return 0;
}
```

With output:

```
Non const-refrence
Non const-refrence
Const-refrence
```

The `const` you see after the second getTest signature tells the compiler that no member variables will be modified as a result of calling this function.

Answer (score 1):

> is it valid if I define member functions with same name&parameters but different return types [...]?

No.
Neither a method class nor a non-class function.

The reason is ambiguity. There would be situation in which the compiler could not pick the right overloading only by deducing the returned value.

In conclusion: you can't overload methods based on return type.

---

In your example, those two methods:

```
 Test& getTest();
 const Test& getTest() const;
```

Are correctly overloaded because the *signature* is different, but *not* because the return value is different!

Indeed, a function signature is made up of:

- function name
- cv-qualifiers
- parameter types
- method qualifier

So the signature of your methods are:

```
1) getTest();
2) getTest() const;
              ^------ Note that const qualifiers of the method is part of signature
```

As you can notice, the return value is *not* part of signature, but the *const* of the method qualifier is.

---

> Which member function gets called if we have following code?

With the following code:

```
Foo foo;
Test& t1 = foo.getTest();
const Test& t2 = foo.getTest();
```

It will call *only the no-const method*, *even* in the case `t2`.

The reason is that `foo` object is `no-const` in that scope, so each
method will be called in its no-const form.

In details, in the third line:

```
const Test& t2 = foo.getTest();
```

`foo.getTest()` will return the `no-const` reference and *after* will
be implicitly converted in a `const` reference.

If you want to force the compiler to call the `const` version, you should "temporary convert" the object `foo` in a `const`.

For example:

```
const int& t2 = static_cast<const Foo&>(foo).getTest();
```

In that case I get a `const` ref to the object, so the object will be treated like a `const` and the proper const method will be invoked.